# How can I convert my MATLAB code into WL code?

Tags: matrix, matlab

I am working in MATLAB and want to convert the following snippet into WL code  to run on Mathematica.

```ml
     u(j,j) = number1(j); //Some function of j that calculates the number
     u(j,j+1) = number2(j);
     u(j,j-1) = numer2(j);
```

The matrix u was not previously initialized. Basically I want to create a matrix which I can continuously append numbers to.

I know how to do something similar with vectors, namely,

```
u = {initialValue}; 
While[..., AppendTo[u, someNumber[i]], ...]
```

Hpw can I extend this to matrices for arbitrary $j$?

Comment: Do you want a matrix with 3 bands? For size 5 try: `SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> number1, Band[{2, 1}] -> number2, Band[{1, 2}] -> number2 }, {5, 5}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: @asterix314 Yes, but I should have added that number1, number2, and number3 change with j. which means that on {1,1} my number is 3, then j increments by one and now on {2,2} my number is 22.. etc.

Comment: Don't ever "extend" matrices, not even in Matlab. Super inefficient.

Answer (score 10):

`SparseArray` is especially versatile with how you specify the elements. E.g.

```
SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> f[i], {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> g[i]}, {5, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

will produce the following matrix:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 f(1) & g(1) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 g(2) & f(2) & g(2) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & g(3) & f(3) & g(3) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & g(4) & f(4) & g(4) \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & g(5) & f(5) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$